# Откуда слово "няня"?

Tags: этимология

Возможно уже был этот вопрос, но я не нашел. Заодно вопрос, может, больше не по русскому, а по литературе:
"Она по-русски плохо знала"
"Изъяснялася с трудом на языке своем родном"
- на каком тогда языке Татьяна разговаривала с **няней**, признавалась ей в любви к Онегину? На ломаном русском? **Няня** говорила по-французски?

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. С большим интересом прочитал все три.

Answer (score 1):

Слово "няня" скорее всего появилось как звукоподражание речи ребёнка, отсюда же такие слова как "мама", "папа", "тятя" и пр.

Answer (score 1):

**1) На каком языке говорила няня Татьяны**

Пушкин не раз говорил о том, что **Арина Родионовна стала прототипом няни главной героини Татьяны в поэме «Евгений Онегин».** [Арина Родионовна — няня Пушкина | wpoet.ru](http://wpoet.ru/%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F/112.html)

Как и все жители села, Арина была **крепостной**, и девочке с малых лет приходилось много работать.  Но в  село иногда приходил настоящий сказочник, пожилой крестьянин, который знал множество сказок и умел талантливо их рассказывать, этим и жил. Арина с восхищением слушала сказочника, а потом пересказывала сказки детворе — **она обладала очень хорошей памятью.  Став замечательной сказочницей,** уже взрослая Арина, которую мы знаем как знаменитую няню Пушкина Арину Родионовну, она передала будущему великому поэту любовь к русскому народному творчеству, **к богатому русскому языку.**

**2) Удивительно то, что слово "няня" отмечено в словаре только в 1704 году,** нянька, нянчить — с 1771 года. Тем не менее можно предположить, что это слово известно с древнейших времен, оно возникло как простейший удвоенный слог в речи ребенка.

Answer (score 1):

```
      Откуда слово "няня"?
```

Семёнов утверждает, что "точное время появления этой лексической единицы в русском языке не установлено, но есть основания полагать, что слово «няня» употребляется в языке с древнейших времен, так как словоформа «нянька» встречается в памятниках письменности с XII в.

Няня – женщина, ухаживающая за детьми.

В других славянских языках есть слова с тем же значением и схожим звучанием.
Родственными являются:
Болгарское – неня.
Польское – nanka.

http://enc-dic.com/semenov/Njanja-1252.html

С няней Татьяна разговаривала не на ломаном русском, а на народном русском, ведь Татьяна росла и воспитывалась в деревне, в традиционной семье 
провинциальных дворян:"Они хранили в жизни мирной привычки милой старины... 
"    Русская природа, атмосфера народных традиций и обычаев, 
"преданья простонародной старины", рассказы няни родили и укрепили 
в сердце девушки любовь, чувство близости к своему народу. 
Общение с природой, близкие доверительные отношения с няней  привели к тому, что она стала «русская душою». Хотя под подушкой у Татьяны лежали романы Ричардсона, ей снились русские сны.

"Изъяснялася с трудом на языке своем родном" - это о письменной речи. Вот писала она, как и все дети дворян, на французском, ведь няня сама была неграмотна и не могла научить её письменному русскому, поэтому и письмо Онегину написано на французском.